# Bulk Upload: "unexpected end of file" on new server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to do a bulk upload in one table in our sql database. This query was running good before, when we had the database on different server, but now on the new server I am getting an error.
Here is all I have:
sql bulk import query:

```
BULK
INSERT NewProducts
FROM 'c:\newproducts.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

And the errors I am getting are:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What are the versions/software on the old and new server?

Answer (score 3):

For anybody else who comes across this question looking for an answer, this error also happens when the number of columns in your CSV file don't match the columns of the table you're doing the bulk insert into.

Comment: I know this is a really old post but mate thank you for this, made me recheck.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this before and there are a few things to look for:

1. Make sure that your csv file doesn't have any blank rows at the top.
2. Make sure that there are no additional blank rows at the end of the file.
3. Make sure that the ROWTERMINATOR is actually `\n` and not `\r\n`

If you do all three of these and are still getting the error let me know.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the help, but I checked for all that stuff, I did a test only with two rows and I still get the same errors

Comment: Did you check in notepad? I've found that Excel is not really very helpful when it comes to tracking down extraneous whitespace.

Comment: yes, in notepad is the same. no extra whitespace everything looks same, I don't know why I am getting that error

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file I was trying to access was in a directory that the SQL Sever process did not have access to.  I moved my flat files to a directory SQL had access to and this error was resolved.